# Ruby copy an array of arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, reference

Is there a way in Ruby to make a copy of multi-dimensional array? I mean some built-in function.

When I try to use .dup it just returns reference:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
irb(main):002:0> b = a.dup
=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
irb(main):003:0> b[0][0] = 15
=> 15
irb(main):004:0> a == b
=> true
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to dup the arrays in the list instead of just the outer one. The easiest way is probably something like

```
b = a.map(&:dup)
```

Comment: I suppose this only works for 1 extra dimension. What about N-dimensions? I suppose dup should be applied recursively on each object.

Answer (score 8):

Marshaling should do the trick:

```
jruby-1.6.7 :001 > a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
 => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] 
jruby-1.6.7 :002 > b = Marshal.load( Marshal.dump(a) )
 => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] 
jruby-1.6.7 :004 > a == b
 => true 
jruby-1.6.7 :005 > b[0][0] = 15
 => 15 
jruby-1.6.7 :006 > a == b
 => false
```